# Is it possible to redirect to another function within a function in PHP?

Tags: php

I am adding a delete button to certain rows of a table (not all). The table is already inside a form, so my thinking is to do a check to see if my button was clicked inside the function that the form submits to and redirect to a delete function if it was. I can't figure out if it's possible to do that or what other options there are.

I tried using a link for the delete, but that doesn't get the information across. I tried using another form, but that's a form within a form. If there is another way to do this, I'm happy to learn it.

Here is parts of the form:

```
echo '<form action="#/job/addorupdate" id="jobform" name="jobform" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="228828">';
    if ($id > 0) {
        echo '<button style="color:red;border:none;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;" type="submit" value="' . $id . '" name="idOfRow">X</button>';
    }
    echo '</form>';
```

Here is the function it goes to:

```
public function addOrUpdate(){ // addOrUpdate a job - control
    if ($this->input->post('idOfRow')) {
        // This is where I want to do the redirect
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: instead you can use Javascript to submit the form.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi, I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi, how do I get all the information across to the JavaScript? I want to submit to a different function.

Comment: Better to add check box on required row. And at end of table add submit button. After click on submit button get all the checked row id  and delete.

Comment: @ShivendraSingh, that's a good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace the button with a link and use that to call the delete function.

```
echo '&nbsp;<a href="' . site_url('#/deleteunrelatedcase/' . $jobid . '/' . $id) . '" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">X</a>';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function addOrUpdate(){ // addOrUpdate a job - control
    if ($this->input->post('idOfRow')) {
        $delete=deleteRow($this->input->post('idOfRow'));
        if($delete == 1){
            header('location:location.php'); // add redirect location here.

        }
    }
}
//Create One New function 
public function deleteRow($DeleteInput){ 
    if ($DeleteInput) {
        //add sql function to delete

        if(delete == true){
           return 1;
        }
        else {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The function I want to redirect to is in another file. How would I do that?

Comment: Include that file here and call that function. If it is oops means you can do this as easily.